# How to use a proxy while opening browsers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically what I want to do is for me to be able to connect to a proxy while I am able to browse the internet

Here is the code I tried

```
import webbrowser
import socks, socket, requests
from multiprocessing import Process

def proxy():
    while True:
          socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "184.32.91.92", 2901)
          socket.socket = socks.socksocket


if __name__ == '__main__':
   proxy_process = Process(target=proxy).start()
   r = requests.get("http://icanhazip.com")
   print(r.content) # stil gives me my actual IP address
   webbrowser.open("http://icanhazip.com", new=2)  # opening the webbrowser
```

So i tried to process the proxy to keep the connection alive but even when I open the browser it still gives me my actual IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a timing issue. Your `__main__` process probably reaches the line:

```
r = requests.get("http://icanhazip.com")
```

before `proxy_process` has done it's job.